# ABS speed sensors not picking values less than 18kp/h

Tags: abs

I have changed the sensors, but both front sensors are not reading the speed values less than 18km/h. Due to which brake and then abs lights come on.
The readings are fine after 18kp/h.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What else have you checked? So we don’t make suggestions and you come back with "already checked that".

Comment: Some suggestions might be improperly gapped sensors, dirty, corroded or damaged tone rings, bad connectors or wiring, or wrong sensors installed. I agree with @Solar Mike more information is needed. Especially year make model and engine size so we can determine what type of abs system you have.

Comment: It is Suzuki Liana 07 model. I had it taken to a mechanic. They have tried replacing the main ABS module/controller as well.

Comment: So far
Replaced sensors,
Replaces abs module,
Checked the rings. But no readings until 17kp/h. After which the brake and abs lights come on.

Comment: If the tone rings are clean and good and with all the other work done the only things that I can think of is either both the abs sensors are not sitting flush to the knuckle, or the wrong sensors were installed. Maybe others can come up with more possibilities.